# Getting null pointer exception when running Nutch crawler 2.2 with Hbase

Tags: hadoop, nutch, web-crawler

when I run the Nutch command: ~/nutch/runtime/deploy$ bin/nutch crawl urls -dir /user/dlequoc/urls -depth 2 -topN 5, I got a following exception:

=======================================================

> 13/08/26 16:30:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 100% reduce 0% 13/08/26
>   16:30:29 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000001_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000005_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000004_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000002_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:32 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000003_0, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:44 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000001_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000000_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000005_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000002_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000004_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:47 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000003_1, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000000_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000002_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:30:59 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000001_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:31:02 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000005_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:31:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000003_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:31:11 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :
>   attempt_201308261546_0004_r_000004_2, Status : FAILED
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.apache.avro.util.Utf8.(Utf8.java:37)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorReducer.setup(GeneratorReducer.java:100)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:174)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:649)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:417)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)  at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249) 13/08/26
>   16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201308261546_0004
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 24 13/08/26
>   16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters  13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Launched reduce tasks=23 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=113452 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after
>   reserving slots (ms)=0 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Rack-local map tasks=1
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=1
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed reduce tasks=1
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=268210 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FileSystemCounters 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE_BYTES_READ=25743276 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   HDFS_BYTES_READ=704 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   FILE_BYTES_WRITTEN=51473783 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   File Input Format Counters  13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Bytes Read=0 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Map-Reduce
>   Framework 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Map output
>   materialized bytes=25720344 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Combine output records=0 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Map input records=333988 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=449036288 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Spilled Records=667976 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Map output bytes=25052332 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     CPU time spent (ms)=81870 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO
>   mapred.JobClient:     Total committed heap usage (bytes)=208011264
>   13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Virtual memory (bytes)
>   snapshot=740638720 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Combine input records=0 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   Map output records=333988 13/08/26 16:31:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:
>   SPLIT_RAW_BYTES=704 Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: job failed: name=generate: null,
>   jobid=job_201308261546_0004   at
>   org.apache.nutch.util.NutchJob.waitForCompletion(NutchJob.java:54)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.GeneratorJob.run(GeneratorJob.java:199)    at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:68)   at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:152)  at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:250)  at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)     at
>   org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:257)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)

could you please help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Command `/bin/nutch crawl` is deprecated in Nutch 2.x. Use `/bin/crawl` instead.